# Definition and declaration of variable with a value

Tags: c, declaration, definition

Just started with `K & R` and on the 2nd chapter, there is the line:

> Declarations list the variables to be
>   used and state what type they have and
>   **perhaps what their initial values are**.

So:

`int x = 42` is a *definition*.

and `int x` is a *declaration* but also a *definition* since every *definition* is a *declaration*.

But when we assign an intial value like `K & R` say, doesn't that make the *declaration* a *definition*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confuse two things:

1. A declaration states (*declares*) what an object's* type, name and scope is
2. A definition *defines* what a object's content is

* object as in: variable, function etc., not an OOP object.

A definition is hence very often also a declaration, since you cannot define what is in an object when you do not state what the type of the object is. Easiest to remember is just: "Every definition is a declaration, but not every declaration is a definition"

**For variables**

There is only 1 way to declare without defining the variable:

```
extern typeX variable_name
```

This tells the compiler that there is a variable called variable_name with type typeX, but not where to get it.
Every other way to declare a variable is also a definition, since it tells the compiler to reserve space for it and perhaps give it an initial value.

The difference is much clearer in structs and functions:

**For Structs**

A declaration:

```
struct some_struct{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

This declares some_struct to the compiler with a and b as struct variables both with type int.

Only when you define them space is reserved and you can use them:

```
void foo(){
    struct some_struct s;
    s.a = 1; // For this to work s needs to be defined
}
```

**For functions**:

The difference is much more clear

declaration:

```
// This tells the compiler that there is a function called "foo" that returns void and takes void arguments
void foo();
```

A definition could be like the one above (in the struct part)

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: Indeed you can't assign a default value to a variable declaration, unless it also is a definition. But as I said: sometimes the terms are used as synonyms.

Unless this is in a part about structs: you can assign default values to the struct it's variables when declaring said struct.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can say that a declaration simply tells the compiler that there is somewhere a variable with that name and type. It does produce any code, and in C, this has to be done with the `extern` keyword on variables. Function prototypes (without implementation) are also mere declarations, and don't need the `extern` keyword, but you can still provide it. 
A definition produces code, e.g. allocates memory on the stack or heap for a variable, or the   body for methods.

In that sense, both of your statments are definitions, and any definition is also a delcaration.

I think that might by a mistake by K&R...